# Get Childs-Parents variables in another Child Object.

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I'm learning oop in php and trying various techniques to get my ahead around the concept.

I've run across this issue in my code (I'll demonstrate) and wondered the best way of achieving this as I'm wrapping myself up in knots trying to get my head around it.

I have the following classes (simplified for my clarity):

```
Vehicle
Car extends Vehicle
Trailer extends Vehicle

Ford extends Car
```

Vehicle has a variable "wheels"

I instantiate a "Ford" which uses the "wheels" variable.

I then want to use the same "wheels" variable in a "Trailer"

Is it possible to instantiate a "Trailer" in such a way as it inherits the common variables already used by my "Ford" object?

As I understand it, creating a "new" object will mean that my "Trailer" is an entirely new instance so will not have access to anything in the "Ford" object.

So I wondered is there a way of creating a "Trailer" whereby it shares the "Fords" variables that are common to them (i.e. the variables in the Vehicle class).

Hope this question is clear enough. I'm just struggling with oop to make "the penny drop" although I do feel I'm getting close to my Eureka moment. Any help in explaining/clarifying things will be appreciated.

:-)

Comment: You could look into static properties. They are tied to the class and not the object.

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen How would that work for this? Not all vehicles have the same number of wheels.

Comment: I cant understand your thought process on this sorry, you want variables shared between objects but only some objects not others based on some unspecified rules?

Comment: As I understand it (and my lack there-of is probably the issue) each class, when it extends another class, has access to its methods and properties. Due to extending classes it is possible to have two branches as detailed in my Vehicles example. The Ford has access to the property "Wheels" from Vehicle class. I would like to have access to this value (and others) from within another Vehicle object. I know I could pass vars through the constructor but wondered if it's possible to 'overlay' in some way, one objects inheritance on to another object. Hope that helps clear up the question.